# Expected value in probability?

Tags: statistics, probability

Isn't the definition of expected value little non mathematical. I mean average is defined when experiment is done, so how can we before hand tell the expected value. Let say for toss, if I get ₹1 for winning and ₹0 for losing then it says after 1000 attempt I will pocket ₹500. There's no way to say so as I can get 0 or 683 or anything. There is not a single theorem which will tell me that it's 500. Physically you may say that you would be close to 500 but then the whole point of mathematics is to remain independent from physics and it's results.

Comment: "it says after 1000 attempt i **will** pocket ₹500" is not true.  "it says after 1000 attempt i **expect to** pocket ₹500" is the correct statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confusing the idea between Theoretical Probability, where we have not yet run the experiment, and Statistics, where we have already completed the experiment.  Certainly if we have already flipped the coin 1000 times and received our money, there is no "expected value" to be calculated.  We got the amount of money that we got and that is it.

However, we are often interested before ever beginning to flip the coin what we *expect* the outcome might be (that is not to say that the outcome *will* be what we expect, but if we were to try multiple times it will average out around there).  Let $X$ be a random variable.  Either it is discrete (takes countably many values) or it is continuous (takes uncountably many values).  We denote $E[X]$ to be the "Expected value of the random variable $X$."

> Discrete case: For outcomes $x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots$ and associated probabilities $p_1,p_2,p_3,\dots$ (I.e. $p_i = Pr(X=x_i)$) you have $E[X] := \sum\limits_{i} x_i p_i$
>
> Continuous case: For sample space $S$ and probability distribution $p(x) = Pr(X=x)$ you have $E[X] := \int_{S} x p(x)dx$

For your specific example, suppose that there are two outcomes: we win \$1 with probability $\frac{1}{2}$, and we win \$0 with probability $\frac{1}{2}$.  I.e. our sample space is $\{0,1\}$ with associated probabilities $\{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\}$.

To calculate the expected value of a single flip, we add together each product of the outcome and the probability.  $E[X]=0\cdot\frac{1}{2}+1\cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$, so we expect to win $\$\frac{1}{2}$ each time we flip the coin.  (Again, it is impossible to *actually get* $\$\frac{1}{2}$ after a single flip, but it *averages out* to that amount per trial if we do it often enough)

Something nice about the expected value operator $E$ is that it is *linear*.  That is to say, $E[\alpha X + \beta Y] = \alpha E[X] + \beta E[Y]$.

To complete your example, "we flip a coin 1000 times, and for each heads you win \$1 and for each tails you win \$0", note that "flipping a coin 1000 times" is the same as "flip a coin" and then "flip a coin" and then ... and then "flip a coin" (a total of 1000 times).  In this case then $E[1000 X] = 1000 E[X] = 1000\cdot \frac{1}{2} = 500$

Answer (score 0):

Expected value of a function is well defined (except in pathological cases).  The expected average function can be defined before an experiment is done (and yes, is governed by theorems).  It is defined based on the limit of an infinite repetition of certain processes (such as flipping a coin).  One can calculate the average value *for your particular* finite set of data, or additionally one can calculate the average for the process under known properties of the function.  Thus one can easily calculate that the expected average return of a fair coin toss for 0 or 1 dollars is exactly 0.5 dollars.  The average for your particular experiment might be, say, 0.46 dollars.